# Filling C++ interface method names in the disassembly in IDA

Tags: ida, c++, vtables

I have a C++ header with interfaces (classes with all methods pure virtual).
I also have a binary which returns pointers to these interfaces.
I debugged while running and received the virtual table addresses for these interfaces' implementation.

Is there a way to tell IDA Pro that the vtable is at a certain address, and to give it the header files and to let it mark all the methods in the vtable and name them accordingly?
There are many interfaces and a lot of methods.

I saw this: [Static analysis of C++ binaries](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87/static-analysis-of-c-binaries), but it doesn't answer the question of automatic naming.

I'm using the freeware version 5.0.

Comment: There are IDC scripts and plugins for RTTI and vtable handling on IDA Palace and other sites (OpenRCE).

Comment: @0xC0000022L OpenRCE seems to be down

Comment: @heinrich5991: Oh, so Pedram actually took it down. Will contact him.

Comment: @heinrich5991 IDA Scripts on OpenRCE: http://www.openrce.org/downloads/browse/IDA_Scripts

Comment: @0xC0000022L Are there plugins for generic (i. e. manual) vtable handling?

Answer (score 9):

If the binary itself has RTTI info compiled in it then you can get at least the names for the vftables, and to some degree a class/struct hierarchy.
For Windows x86 you can use [my IDA plug-in "Class Informer"](http://www.macromonkey.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=705).
Also see for reference [Reversing Microsoft Visual C++ Part II: Classes, Methods and RTTI](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) by igorsk.

Otherwise AFAIK (and know the area well) I doubt there is a plug-in that exists to do what you want.
While structures exist in IDA, C++ classes don't. C++ is not part of IDA's world directly. 
That's more in the realm of a particular language, one of many, while IDA is about assembly and byte code domains; with the exception of the HexRays decompiler plug-in, which sort of adds a C/C++ thing on top.

Are you sure you can relate the actual binary address to a given C++ method, and, or vftable et al?

At any rate you will probably have to write your own plug-in, and, or scripts to do what you want.

Comment: Your website appears to be down.